# admob, cycling through ads on an interval

Tags: java, android, admob

I finally got AdMob to work on an android game I made, but it only displays 1 ad for the duration of the game session. It would be nice if there was a timer that loaded a new ad every  2 minutes or so. Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes go into your admob account click manage settings under your app then click the app settings tab. then go down to automatic refresh and set what you want.

You can also set it in code.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend actually NOT refreshing ads too often. You are far likelier to get a click-through (therefore higher revenue) if you are showing the same ad throughout the app and not refreshing it so often.

Comment: Ive stressed about this very aspect. :( I do not know which is the more efficient model : 1 ad for 20 minutes vs 10 ads 2 minutes each.

Comment: If the user is presented with the same ad for a long period, they're far likelier to click on it than multiple ads in a shorter period.